# Where is the "Use Auto Layout" checkbox in Xcode 12?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have started using Xcode for the first time in a long time.
The version of Xcode is 12.

I created a new project of Swift with the interface of Storyboard instead of SwiftUI.
Then I selected Main.storyboard in the left pane of Xcode and put a UILabel onto the View Controller.
I found that there was not the "Use Auto Layout" checkbox which had been in the right pane of the Inteface Builder of old Xcode.

Where is it in the version 12 of Xcode?

Is there a way to use the auto layout system in Xcode 12?

Answer (score 4):

The checkbox was removed because autolayout is now the default. Just make a constraint and it springs to life for any view(s) affected by that constraint.

A view completely untouched by constraints still uses the auto resizing mask.

There is a way to subvert that behavior for an individual view; but don't.

Comment: Also you should check "Use Trait Variations" and "Use Safe Area Layout Guides" if they are not already checked.